# how to Generate xlsx file and automatically download it in Python-Django

Tags: python

I have a download button that supposedly download a data to xlsx file.
So in views.py I have this codes to generate xlsx file with data but I dunno how to automatically download it, send help pls.

```
import os
import csv
import io
import xlsxwriter
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from pathlib import Path


@csrf_exempt
def TestDl(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            downloads_path = str(Path.home() / "Downloads")
            path = downloads_path + "/demo.xlsx"

            # Create an new Excel file and add a worksheet.
            workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path)
            worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

            # Widen the first column to make the text clearer.
            worksheet.set_column('A:A', 50)

            # Add a bold format to use to highlight cells.
            bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

            # Write some simple text.
            worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello')

            # Text with formatting.
            worksheet.write('A2', 'World', bold)

            # Write some, with row/column notation.
            worksheet.write(2, 3, 312) # Number automatically positioned at the right side of a column
            worksheet.write(2, 8, 'asd')
            worksheet.write(3, 5, 'hfgh')
            worksheet.write(5, 2, '312')

            workbook.close()

            return JsonResponse({"result": "success"}, safe=False)
        except:
            return JsonResponse({"result": "error"}, safe=False)

    return JsonResponse({"result": "failed"}, safe=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

forgot to answer this when I already have the solution.
Anyway, what I did was I created a folder inside the static folder and then made it the path where the created xlsx file will be saved.

and then add these codes in the javascript where I declared the download click function.

```
downloadURI(static_path, filename)

function downloadURI(uri, name) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    delete link;
}
```